# ImageIcon is not setting given color on safari, it shows black icon

Tags: flutter, dart, safari

Below is my sample code :

```
  _getIcon(String iconName, {color}) {

    return Container(
        child: ImageIcon(
      AssetImage('assets/images/' + iconName),
      color: color,
    ));
  }
```

i am calling it as :

```
_getIcon("sampleImage.png", Color("0xFF0065A3"))
```

Above code works perfectly fine on chrome , but it's not setting given color on safari. It shows black icon.

Below is my build command :

```
flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer html
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with

```
flutter run -d chrome --release --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
```

or you can build a web with

```
 flutter build web --release --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
```

if FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true causes an issue with other widgets/fonts so instead of that command you can use

```
 flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Comment: with "flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit" it was causing flashing/flickering  issue on safari . Thats why we switched to  web-renderer html.

We give a second try with FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA

Comment: @Sheetal Savani did you get any solution for this?

Comment: The mentioned command worked for me @developer